# Is it possible to access variables from inside a cypress block, outside of it

Tags: csv, cypress

what i need to do is, in cypress, pull in a csv that has all of my test data but also all of my expected results and the code should look at the expected results and say "if there is an expected result, build the associated test at run time to check that result" this works in postman.. however that would have to have my csv file pulled in, then be outside of an it / before / beforeeach block to then say if an expected result exists build an it block..

unfortunately the only way i have found to successfully load up a csv is to use cy.fixture and when you use cy.fixture anything it loads cannot be accessed outside of a before / beforeEach or It etc.

example:

```js
const csv = require ('neat-csv');
let csvData
before(() => {
  cy.fixture('33688-DASH-ERS-FullSchemeTest.csv').then(csv).then((data) => {
    csvData = data
})

console.log(csvData) //undefined

it('test', () => {
console.log(csvData) //shows my CSV
})
```

```
however i start off with let csvData = {} and then have line 4 say csvData.csv = data, then when i console log it on line 7 it will log as an empty object but if you click the object you can see everything inside of it.

So there's obviously something weird going on with how cypress operates here, is there any way i can get access to that csvData outside of a cy block?

I've tried activating neat-csv without cy fixture, using chatGPT to help me understand how to use a webpack preprocessor on cypress etc but i am not that experienced and just hit error after error
```

Comment: You may save it as an Environment Variable in the first test case and then it could be accessbiel from  the other test case as well. see https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/env

Answer (score 3):

You are logging to console before the test has run.

The code is not executed in the linear way you describe.

- Cypress uses javascript to execute the code and **discover what commands** you want to run
- during that first execution it performs your `console.log()` on **empty variable**
- now test runs
- `before()` runs first and gets the fixture, sets `csvData`
- `it()` runs next and uses `csvData`

---

If you want to use `csvData` outside of `it()` block, use `require()` at the top of the spec file to load `csvData` early.

```js
const csvData = require('cypress/fixture/33688-DASH-ERS-FullSchemeTest.csv')  

// csvData is now available outside of it()
// for example, you can use csvData to generate tests
csvData.forEach(data => {

  it('Data: ' + data.id, () => {
    ...
```